# Angular 6 : search in direct in a table without press enter

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a search  where my table is filtered in direct when I'm writing a letter in my input with angular 6.
Here you van find my function search :

```
template: `
<input #search class="search" type="text" placeholder="   Recherche globale" 
(keydown.enter)="onSearch(search.value)">`

constructor() {
this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data);
}

onSearch(query: string = '') {
 if (query === '') {
   this.source.reset();
 } else {
this.source.setFilter([
  // fields we want to include in the search
  {
    field: 'SITE',
    search: query
  },
  {
    field: 'FILIERE',
    search: query
  },
  {
    field: 'TYPE',
    search: query
  },
  {
    field: 'TYPESOURCE',
    search: query
  },
  {
    field: 'MOTIFNOTIF',
    search: query
  },
], false);
}
```

I would like to apply this "dynamic search" on all my `field`.

Comment: Where are you having a problem with this? What is the question here?

Comment: `ng-repeat` is for angularJS not for angular6

Comment: @sabithpocker, search is working but when i press enter button, I want a dynamic search.

Comment: change (keydown.enter)="onSearch(search.value)" by (input)="onSearch(search.value)" or by  (keyup)="onSearch(search.value)"

Comment: It works perfectly @Eliseo. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also use an RxJs Subject and update its value on keyup, then you can use debounceTime to avoid search on each keyup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Eliseo, we just have to change `(keydown.enter)="onSearch(search.value)"` by `(input)="onSearch(search.value)"`